# How to use the comment update service in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sql-server, web-services, auto-update

I have created an app in objective C, In this app i have one page there User can comment live and for the updating comments i am hitting every 5 min the web-service. I have no idea about the server data change .

I want to hit the service while the data has been change to the server. 
Is it possible . Or we can use some other way for the web services.

Thanks, Please answer if you have an correct way to solve it.

Comment: You would typically use push notifications for this, but you could also use a websocket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to this web site [PubNub](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/ios-objective-c/pubnub-objective-c-sdk-v4), download SDK's for both Server and Objective-C. PubNub is a common Stream Service with Subscribe/Publish services. After implementing SDK's, make your Client as Subscriber, and make your Server as Publisher. Simply; Subscribers are listening channels for data. When you have a new comment, Publish that comment from Server to channel which your client has already subscribed. Do not forget, free accounts are for demo purposes and have limitations.

Comment: Is there any thing free or not ?

Comment: @AbhishekMishra There are several. Pusheo, SocketRocket etc. I'm using PubNub. That's why I've suggested.